Not able to insert other fields for contact record
I am new to cumulusci. I could create contact with first and last names, but I could not insert a record with other fields. It keep throwing below error.
Element with locator '//div[contains(@class, 'modal-container')]//label[@for!='' and text()='Location ']|//label[@for!=''][./span[text()='Location ']]' not found.
Here's my code:
Via UI
    ${first_name} =       Get fake data  first_name
    ${last_name} =        Get fake data  last_name

    Go to page            Home  Contact
    Click Object Button   New
    Click Modal Button    Next
    Wait for modal        New  Contact

    Populate Form
    ...                   First Name=${first_name}
    ...                   Last Name=${last_name}
    ...                   Location = NY



Have you already checked the CumulusCI community group?

I figured out the problem. It was an issue with the spacing between Location and value. Thank you.

I figured out the problem. It was an issue with the spacing between Location and value.
